# One Accordion to multiple views

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, view, jquery-ui-accordion

I may be trying to do things using a "handy hammer" methodology, but hopefully somebody out there has tried this as well.

Basically, I have one page with multiple views, I would like to use the jQuery accordion feature to be able to toggle them on and off.

For example:
There is a view entitled "Press Releases" and other called "Recent Blog Posts"
I would like clicking on these headers to open and close the view contents.

I guess I want to have step back from the views-accordion so that instead of the interior content items being expandable, that all the content items would expand.

Hope this makes sense!

If there is a softer and easier way of doing this, I am all ears!

Comment: how are the Views put into the page?